# What is a focal copy number variation?

Tags: genetics, terminology, copy-number-variation

Often, genetics studies, especially genome wide ones, talk about "focal copy number variations" in genes or regions of the chromosome. I know what a copy number variation is. What does "focal" mean, exactly?

Are there non-focal CNVs? What are they? Where did the term "focal" originate? Is there a specific paper that coined (and hopefully unambiguously defined) the term?

A search for "focal copy number variation" on Google Scholar should turn up plenty of papers *about it*. The GISTIC algorithm is a popular computational method for finding putative CNVs- so information about this algorithm may have some clues.

A [documentation text](ftp://ftp.broadinstitute.org/pub/genepattern/modules_public_server_doc/GISTIC.pdf) for one GISTIC implementation on the Broad Institute's website states the following:

> (8) Broad or Focal: Identifies whether the region reaches significance due 
>   primarily to broad events (called “broad”), focal events (called “focal”), or 
>   independently significant broad and focal events (called “both”).

Comment: You could probably even call an aneuploidy (variation in chromosome number) a CNV. So that’s pretty large-scale.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A copy number variation (CNV) is when the number of copies of a particular gene varies from one individual to the next.
>
> From: [the NIH Glossary](http://ghr.nlm.nih.gov/glossary=copynumbervariation)

Focal CNVs are regions of repeated genetic information that only span a small proportion  (<25%) of the chromosome arm (although this does not seem to be a consistent rule), and can contain few genes. CNVs greater than this are termed either 'large-scale' or 'broad'.

---

Here are some relevant papers I came across (no doubt there are more);

This paper is about a program (VarScan2) the authors have made to robustly detect somatic mutations and CNVs;

> To identify SCNAs [*somatic copy number alterations*], VarScan 2 compares Q20 (base quality >=20) read depths between tumor and normal samples for contiguous regions of coverage ... Therefore, we apply a circular binary segmentation (CBS) algorithm (Seshan and Olshen 2010) to delineate segments by copy number and identify significant change-points. **A subsequent joining procedure merged adjacent segments of similar copy number and classified them as either large-scale (>25% of chromosome arm) or focal events.**
>
> From: [Koboldt D, *et al*, 2012](http://dx.doi.org/10.1101/gr.129684.111).

I continued searching, as I wondered whether this was a standard definition, or just one used by the authors.

This paper is reporting bacterial genes that drive focal chromosomal aberrations, but do not give a great definition (as it seem quite arbitrary to me);

> Many of these [chromosomal] aberrations concern large chromosomal regions, which makes it difficult to identify actual driver genes. Increased resolution has led to the detection of **focal chromosomal aberrations, defined as 3 Mb or smaller in size** [5–8]. Inherent to their size, focal aberrations contain a small number of genes, facilitating driver gene identification
>
> From: [Brosens R, *et al*, 2010](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/path.2724).

This extract is from one of the studies referenced by the previous paper (when they mention their definition of focal CNVs). This paper is about CNVs in different tumour cells;

> Primary tumors contain varying proportions of nonneoplastic cells thereby obscuring focal amplifications, defined by the increased copy number of a small region of the genome, from simple gains of whole chromosome arms.
>
> From: [Leary RJ, *et al*, 2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0808041105).